# In R, how do you accumulate data from inside a loop to a numeric vector above the loop

Tags: r, vector

I have a problem in R trying to accumulate data that is gathered inside a for loop, that will iterate 200 + times before it ends, into a numeric vector defined before the loop starts. When the function returns the results it is apparent that the vector is only holding data from the last iteration of the loop. See the following pseudo codish example:

```
results <- numeric()

for(i in records) 
    a <- read a record in
    b <- identify complete cases in a
    c < sum(b)
    if(c < 10)
         d <- strip out rows with NAs in a
         results <- cor(d[3:4])
    endif
    print results
end
```

One thing I am fairly certain of is that I need to some how define the length of "results" but the exact size is unknown until the function ends.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: `results <- c(results, cor(d[3:4]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alex points out you can extend the vector like this:

```
results <- c(results, cor(d[3:4]))
```

or you can extend it implicitly like this:

```
results[i] <- cor(d[3:4])
```

or you can use the above line in conjunction with initializing the full 
length vector like this:

```
results <- numeric(length(numeric()))
```